# Convert SSL .p12 to .pem with or without OpenSSL

Tags: java

I have .p12 file that need to be converted to .pem file - I add a username and password in the process.

Using openssl, the command is...

`openssl pkcs12 -in PassbookCert.p12 -clcerts -nokeys -out passcertificate.pem -passin pass:`

I can run this from a terminal session and it works perfectly.

However, I will need to do this often and I want to write a java code for this. What is the best way to do it?

Comment: Because this is the command which I am executing when I was creating a .pkpass manually but now when it's the time to automate it, I am converting all the steps followed into java code. Now I am stuck at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this in java! Seriously.

Depending on your operating system, try a for-loop in bash when being on linux, or some powershell or whatever is used on Windows (batch scripts?). On a mac you will also have a shell which will work like a linux.

Something like this:

```
for i in *; do openssl pkcs12 -in "$i".p12 -clcerts -nokeys -out "$i".pem -passin pass; done
```

For illustration purposes, cannot be used in terminal directly:

```
for i in *
do 
    openssl pkcs12 -in "$i".p12 -clcerts -nokeys -out "$i".pem -passin pass
done
```

Maybe you should not use the same password on all files, but this should do.

If you do not want to use this directly on the terminal from within the folder where you only have your certfiles located, you can also put this into a scriptfile and do some more stuff with it.

Create an empty text file, put a shebang in the first line (`#!/bin/bash`), the code on the line below.
Make the file executable (`chmod +x filename`) and then you can run it directly. (`./filename`)

You can pass parameters to bash scripts, too.

Comment: Actually I want to create it like a service, when some person comes to my website and books a ticket for an event then during the last step of sending the eticket through email, I will be attaching my generated event.pkpass that an iPhone user can open in passbook. I have everything ready except this part.